# Android Listview, Handle clickable textviews

Tags: android, onclick, android-listview

In my android project I am Using a custom listview to show information. In each element of the listview(Each row in list view) have several clickable forcussable textviews. And I added lstvw.setItemsCanFocus(true), for listview and now i can select any clickable textview and click.

```
----------------
textviewclick1
textviewclick2
----------------
textviewclick1
textviewclick2
----------------
continue......
```

But can't figure out how exactly handle the onClick event for each clickable textview as getView() method in the BaseAdapter class is bit confusing for me.

I implemented onclickListener in the ListviewAdapter class that I extended BaseAdapter and created.

```
public class ListVWAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{ implementation...}
```

can anyone suggest me how to handle onClick(View view) method to handle all the clickable textview items.
I  tried following way but did't work correct. I globally declared the ViewHolder viewholder since I want to access it in this method rather than declaring it in normal way within the getView() method. But initializing normal way by checking `if (convertView == null)`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==holder.txtViewTitle)
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Link1 : "+ String.valueOf(currentPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(v==holder.txtViewDescription)
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Link2 : "+ String.valueOf(currentPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: implement the onClickListener in activity class not in addapter.

Comment: When I implement onClickListener to ListView on Activity class it gives an exception. Can give setOnItemClickListener. But useless since the textviews are focussable="true", this method does not get invoked

Comment: But that is the correct way. You should fix the exception. What is exception?

Comment: When I catch the exception by logs it says, Don't call setOnClickListener for an adapter view. You probably need setOnItemClickListener Insted. But as I said before, no use of calling setOnItemClickListener because the textvies are focussable, this method does not get invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In list item xml, for `<TextView..>` set `android:onClick="onFirstLinkClick"`. Similarly for second TextView.
Then in activity class implement this

```
public void onFirstLinkClick(View V) {
    // handle click
}
```

Similarly another method for second textview.  That should work.

Comment: " but implement the click listener in activity class", I don't understand this part. I checked, but didn't find an event called click listener.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the answer...In that way we can handle which link clicked. But how to track the position that clicked(In listview which item the user click)????

Comment: `setTag(position)` to textview in `getView()` method. then in onclick  do `getTag()` to get the item position. Acceptable answer. :)

Comment: Thanks  user7777777777 ....!!! It Works fine. Now I can Handle the listview as I want... Thank you very much for your time. Great..!!!!!

Comment: @userSeven7s+1...It worked but I am still in dilemma.How will I get the text from that textview.